# After loading React Component present modally from Native, how to dismiss modal from React Native and back to previous in ios

Tags: ios, react-native

In my current iOS project I'm loading the `React Component` which contains the `navigation bar` with `navigation item` 'Cancel' from native 'ViewController'.

When user tap on the 'Cancel' bar button then it should back previous viewController i.e native.

It becomes blocker for me. Can some one please help me to overcome this.

[Native View ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdqwB.png)

[React Component ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik3H6.png)

Below is my code

// ViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "ReactNativeObjCViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)moveToNext:(id)sender
{
  ReactNativeObjCViewController *rootViewController = (ReactNativeObjCViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReactNativeVC"];

  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
}
```

// ReactNativeObjCViewController.h

```
#import "ReactNativeObjCViewController.h"

#import "ReactNativeViewObjC.h"

@interface ReactNativeObjCViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ReactNativeViewObjC *reactViewWrapper;

@end

@implementation ReactNativeObjCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"React Wrapper (Obj C)";


  self.reactViewWrapper.data = [@{
                                  @"content": @"Welcome to React Native"
                                  } mutableCopy];

  [self.reactViewWrapper initializeReactView];


}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

// ReactNativeViewObjC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ReactNativeViewObjC : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *data;
- (void) initializeReactView;
@end
```

//ReactNativeViewObjC.m

```
#import "ReactNativeViewObjC.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"


@implementation ReactNativeViewObjC

-(void) initializeReactView {


  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"devdactic_tabs" initialProperties:nil
      launchOptions:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  rootView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [self addSubview:rootView];

  NSDictionary *views = @{@"rootView": rootView};
  NSArray *constraints = @[];
  constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[rootView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[rootView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

  [self addConstraints:constraints];
  [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
@end
```

/* JS files */

// index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,

} from 'react-native';


var Welcome = require('./Welcome');

var Featured = require('./Featured');

class devdactic_tabs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'featured'
    };
  }

    render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS 
        unselectedTintColor="white"
                tintColor={'#c1d82f'}

        barTintColor="darkslateblue"
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
        title= "Featured"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
//          icon={{uri:'featured'}}
          onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                  selectedTab: 'featured',
              });
          }}>
            <Featured/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          title="More"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'more'}
//          icon={{uri:'contacts'}}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'more',
                });
          }}>
          <Welcome/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('devdactic_tabs', () => devdactic_tabs);
```

// Welcome.js

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS    
} from 'react-native';

var WelcomeView = require('./WelcomeView');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#123456',
  }
});

class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS 
        initialRoute={{
        component:WelcomeView,
        leftButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
        title:'More',
        }}
        style={{flex:1}}
        />
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Welcome;
```

// WelcomeView.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import 
{
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ListView,
    TabBarIOS,
    NavigatorIOS,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
    TouchableHighlight

} from 'react-native';

var BookDetails = require('./BookDetails');



    var FAKE_BOOK_DATA = [
    {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", description: "Une édition de référence des Contes de ma mère l’Oye de Charles Perrault, spécialement conçue pour la lecture sur les supports numériques. « Cependant les fées commencèrent à faire leurs dons à la princesse. La plus jeune lui donna pour don qu’elle serait la plus belle personne du monde ; celle d’après, qu’elle aurait de l’esprit comme un ange ; la troisième, qu’elle aurait une grâce admirable à tout ce qu’elle ferait ; la quatrième, qu’elle danserait parfaitement bien ; la cinquième, qu’elle chanterait comme un rossignol ; la sixième, qu’elle jouerait de toutes sortes d’instruments dans la dernière perfection. Le rang de la vieille fée étant venu, elle dit, en branlant la tête encore plus de dépit que de vieillesse, que la princesse se percerait la main d’un fuseau, et qu’elle en mourrait. » (Extrait de La Belle au Bois dormant.)", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://books.google.com/books/content?id=PCDengEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/m7G-weBZPYfnoqSiF59LIPPYOuM=/44x81/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/97/47/10974721_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/Q8IBqX3b-nhEAEYokJ_aH6jO6lE=/54x78/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/94/13/10941373_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/e3AKmyWuh1Wr4qMAM_vQ0vtN9AA=/54x77/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/94/13/10941368_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/1FxtmlxCqRb0EPdHFrFDGpZ45CE=/54x75/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/31/16/311623_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/yFgYWViboAAdHG99EoF3VULEblc=/54x74/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/97/67/10976773_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/d7ZWFBXpcaqXbOJ-W57_b8B2TR0=/54x80/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/92/85/10928519_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Catcher in the Rye', authors: "J. D. Salinger", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/d7ZWFBXpcaqXbOJ-W57_b8B2TR0=/54x80/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/10/92/85/10928519_ori.jpg'}}}, {volumeInfo: {title: 'The Finisher', authors: "K. L. Rotery", update: "Coming soon!", imageLinks: {thumbnail: 'https://resizing.flixster.com/Yttvb_8gXph4S7iJCiLQFbZ2s7Q=/54x74/dkpu1ddg7pbsk.cloudfront.net/movie/11/00/22/11002233_ori.jpg'}}}
];

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({

});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 10
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    rightContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 8
    },
    author: {
        color: '#656565'
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
    },
    listView: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    loading: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

class WelcomeView extends Component{

    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
           })
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        var books = FAKE_BOOK_DATA;
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(books)
    });

    }

    render(){
        return(
        <ListView 
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}

            ></ListView>
        );
    }


    renderBook(book){
        return(

        <TouchableHighlight onPress= {() => this.showDetails(book)}
            underlayColor='#dddddd'>    
        <View>    
            <View style={styles.container}>

               <Image source={{uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}
                style={styles.thumbnail}/>
               <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.publisher}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</Text>

                        </View>
               </View>

            <View style={styles.separator} />

            </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }

   showDetails(book){

       this.props.navigator.push({
            title: book.volumeInfo.title,
            component: BookDetails,
            passProps: {book}
        });
   }

}

module.exports = WelcomeView;
```

// Featured.js

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS,
  NativeModules

} from 'react-native';



var FeaturedList = require('./FeaturedList');

let DismissViewControllerManager = NativeModules.DismissViewControllerManager;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});

class Featured extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: FeaturedList,
          title: 'Featured',
          leftButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
        onLeftButtonPress: () => this._handleNavigationRequest(),
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }


    _handleNavigationRequest() {
    DismissViewControllerManager.goBack();
  }
}

module.exports = Featured;
```

// FeaturedListView

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
var REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:fiction';

var BookDetails = require('./BookDetails');

import {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ListView,
    TabBarIOS,
    NavigatorIOS,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
    TouchableHighlight
    } from 'react-native';



var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 10
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    rightContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 8
    },
    author: {
        color: '#656565'
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
    },
    listView: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    loading: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

class MoreView extends Component{


    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
           })
       };
   }

    componentDidMount() {


        this.fetchData();
    }


    fetchData() {

        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.items),
                    isLoading: false
                });
            })
            .done();
    }


    render(){

         if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return this.renderLoadingView();
        }

        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderBook.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}
                />
        );


    }

    renderLoadingView() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.loading}>
                <ActivityIndicatorIOS
                    size='large'/>
                <Text>
                    Loading books...
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderBook(book) {
       return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress ={() => this.showBookDetails(book)} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Image
                            source={{uri: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}
                            style={styles.thumbnail} />
                        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.authors}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.volumeInfo.publisher}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</Text>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.separator} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
       );
   }


   showBookDetails(book){

      this.props.navigator.push({
            title: book.volumeInfo.title,
            component: BookDetails,
            passProps: {book}
        });
   }

}


module.exports = MoreView;
```

// BookDetails.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    ScrollView
    } from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 75,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        width: 107,
        height: 165,
        padding: 10
    },
    description: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#656565'
    },
    scrollContainer: {
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        padding: 10
    },
});

class BookDetails extends Component {
    render() {
        var book = this.props.book;
        var imageURI = (typeof book.volumeInfo.imageLinks !==   'undefined') ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : '';
        var description = (typeof book.volumeInfo.description !== 'undefined') ? book.volumeInfo.description : '';
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: imageURI}} />
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = BookDetails;
```

Comment: share the code where you are doing that transition.

Comment: added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Does "WelcomeView back button" work properly?

Comment: That is my question, I was struck, how to implement the 'Cancel' button action that will dismiss the React component and get back to native.

Comment: ScreenShots added, Please have a look and provide the proper solution.